# How to change Bootstrap 3 default column number in less file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I would like to know how I can change the default number of columns (12) in Bootstrap 3. I have found this in the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less)

```
@grid-columns: 12;
```

and I assume that's what I need. Problem is I don't know which `.less` file it is included. And furthermore I don't know how the further procedure will be? I'm having a [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) background but have heard that less is not precombiled? So if I change the value in the -unknown- .less file, would that already work? I really appreciate if someone could guide me through.

Thanks

**Note:** I know there is a custom [download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) builder, but I want to have an overview about the components of Bootstrap 3 and don't want to rebuild when I just want to change a number very quickly.

**Less file:** The less is found and it is `variables.less` and `line: 303`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not already familiar with LESS, you can create a custom download of the compiled source from the [Bootstrap Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) page.  Just edit the grid columns on that page, modify any other options that you want and click the download at the bottom of the page.

If you want to customize the LESS files yourself, you can download them and compile them locally.  If you're familiar with Grunt there is a **[plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less)** you can use to compile your LESS files.  There are also many standalone compilers you can use.  One that is free and cross platform is **[CRUNCH](http://crunchapp.net/)**.

Comment: okay that means, the less files need to be compiled. Since I have the info less can work without precompiling?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.  Can you ask it a different way?  If you have less files you need to compile them into CSS for the browser to understand them.  In development environments, you can use the less.js file to support less files without compiling them, but it's not recommended for production environments.  You can download the less.js here: https://github.com/less/less.js/

Comment: you understood it right. This was basically the question I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variable for adjusting the global grid column value is contained in the variables.less file. The variables.less file is referenced via an @import statement inside the bootstrap.less file.

```html
bootstrap/
├── less/
│   ├── bootstrap.less  (@import 'variables.less')
│   ├── ...
│   ├── variables.less
...
```

The full LESS code base for version 3.2.0 is here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.2.0.zip

Comment: thank you, I found that line of code. But is this automatically applied when I just change the number? Do I need to do some compiling stuff?